# Ignore Untrusted Server Certificate with Salesforce1

Tags: salesforce1-app, ssl

We're setting up forward proxies to access Salesforce (eg, https://localsfdc). We're in dev still so accessing https://localsfdc results to a cert error that testers can easily ignore from their desktop browsers.

However, if I configure the Salesforce1 mobile app to use https://localsfdc, I get the cert error but it does not give me the option to proceed any further.

What are my options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your certificate has to be trusted. This is a requirement of OAuth2, not just Salesforce1. This also means that you can't use http; a successful connection requires https. Fortunately, all major brands of mobile devices have a way to import this file.

First, set up a self-signed certificate on your web server. Next, import your certificate onto your device. Finally, test the configuration to make sure it works.

Specific instructions will depend in your server and mobile device. You should use your favorite search engine to find suitable instructions.

Actual implementation time should be less than five minutes, but your millage may vary.

Comment: I changed the URL to https. The certificates are on the web server, but do our testers need to upload the certificate on their device in order to get past the cert error on SF1?

Comment: Yes, you have to trust it in each and every device you're testing on. This is an intentional breach of security, which is why you have to go through those steps.